# Regex to trim all spaces before and after delimiter Spark Scala

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, delimiter, rdd

I am reading a delimited textfile in with spark scala. I am trying to create a regex trim for everything before the delimiter ~ and everything after. Currently, I have it where all spaces are trimmed. I am looking for any suggestions on how to accomplish this or improvements. Perhaps some sort of trim function would be simpler.

```
 def truncateRDD(fileName : String): RDD[String] = {
    val rdd = sc.textFile(fileName)
    rdd.map(lines => lines.replaceAll("""[\t\p{Zs}]+""", ""))
  }
```

Input:

```
20161111 ~     ~10~1234~ "This is an example" ~P15~-EXAMPLE~2017~ 2014567EXAMPLE
```

Desired Output:

```
20161111~~10~1234~"This is an example"~P15~-EXAMPLE~2017~2014567EXAMPLE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would probably be to split by your delimiter (`~`) and then `trim` each resulting token; Then - combine the tokens back into a single String using `mkString`:

```
rdd.map(_.split("~").map(_.trim).mkString("~"))
```

Alternatively - using a regex:

```
rdd.map(_.replaceAll("\\s*?~\\s*", "~"))
```